# npm start Failed: at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:135:12)

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I am totally new in React/nodjs world, but I am struggling with it for couple of days.
I have installed node-v13.50.0-x64
Then I have run following commands:

```
npm install expo-cli --global

expo init myproject
```

Then navigate to [myproject] location, finally run myproject:

```
npm start
```

But the procees got broken every time and I got following error:

```
events.js:282

      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:129:28)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (J:\React\NetNinja\myproject\node_m
odules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:305:20)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:135:12) {
  errno: -4094,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  filename: null
}
```

package.json

```
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried to install npm again and tried to downgrade to older node js  but it is it still give same error.

Please help.

Comment: And you checked the expo-cli issue tracker first?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
remove node_modules folder: `rm -rf node_modules/`. Then type: `npm install` & `npm update`, 
after: `npm start`

Comment: Note the Windows path in that error log: `rm` is likely not going to do much =) That said, deleting the node_modules folder and clearing the npm cache (`npm cache clean --force`) is before rerunning `npm install` is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It has to deal with Watchman.  All you have to do is go into the project folder from the terminal and run:

`brew update`

`brew reinstall watchman`

This should clear up the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure Windows doesn't run `brew`.